# Using JQuery to build table from JSON object with varying quantity of fields

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

Firstly, apologies for any rather haphazard or completely silly coding no-no's. As this is a first attempt at doing something like this for me. So I'm kind of learning on the fly.

I'm attempting to use JQuery. $.each() to iterate through a JSON object, that has been returned using an Ajax call, to build a table of the results of a search.

The results and as such, the table, will have varying quantities of fields depending upon the type of search that the user has entered. The below example is contains only 3 fields, whereas other searches can be as many as 8 fields.

An example structure of the JSON object that my server side script returns for one type of search is as follows:

```
{"header": 
    {"0": "DRAWING_ID", "1": "FILENAME", "2": "LAST UPDATED"}, 
"results": 
    {"1": {"DRAWING_ID": "15682", "LAST UPDATED": "2015-02-27 10:50:47", "FILENAME": "10-22-2008-K_Shared Sports Analysis Tools"}, 
     "2": {"DRAWING_ID": "7162", "LAST UPDATED": "2015-02-10 07:42:55", "FILENAME": "10-22-2001-BT_Salt And Pepper"}, 
     "3": {"DRAWING_ID": "20429", "LAST UPDATED": "2015-01-26 11:19:40", "FILENAME": "10-22-2006-G_Public Area Fibre"}, 
     "4": {"DRAWING_ID": "7163", "LAST UPDATED": "2014-12-01 23:20:57", "FILENAME": "10-22-2003-AL_Ref Dist"}, 
     "5": {"DRAWING_ID": "17265", "LAST UPDATED": "2013-11-11 16:07:56", "FILENAME": "10-22-2009-B_ Shared Area Monitor"}}}
```

I have chosen to separate out the header and fields and then use the values from the header as keys for the results.

Using JQuery I have been able to draw the HTML table `<th>` elements for the headers using `$.each()` successfully. Yet have been unable to get the same outcome for the results.

The code snippet from `drawTable()` for the `<th>` section is as follows:

```
function drawTable( data ) {
    $("#resultsTable").empty();
    $("#resultsTable").append(function(){
          $.each(data.header, function(index, element) {
            console.log(index,element)
            $("#resultsTable").append($("<th>").text(data.header[index]));
          });
        }).wrapInner("<tr></tr>");
```

Each time this drawTable function is called by the Ajax callback, it empties the last table and redraws. The result of the above is:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="resultsTable">
    <tr><th>DRAWING_ID</th><th>FILENAME</th><th>LAST UPDATED</th></tr>
</table>
```

The results data has given me the biggest problem and I have not been able to puzzle of how to fix it.
The last snippet of `drawTable()` which deals with the remaining rows of the table is as follows:

```
$.each(data.results, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element)
            $("#resultsTable").append($("<tr>").text(function(){
                $.each(element, function(index2, element2) {
                    console.log(element2)
                    $("<td>").text(element2);
                })
            }));
        });
```

Which results in a bunch of empty rows:

```
<tbody>
    <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

I have tried this in a slightly different way which results in all of the `<td>` cells on a single row. But I cannot seem to get them to be wrapped by each of the `<tr></tr>` rows.

Actually, I have been able to successfully draw a similar table by directly indexing each cell that needs to be appended to the table and then wrapping the entire lot in the `<tr></tr>`. Like this:

```
$.each(data.design.results, function(index, element) {
          $("#resultsTable").append($("<tr>").append(
          console.log(data.design.results[index]),
          $("<td>").text(data.design.results[index].LOCATION),
          $("<td>").text(data.design.results[index].SYSN),
          $("<td>").text(data.design.results[index].MODEL),
          $("<td>").text(data.design.results[index].FUNCTION)).attr('onclick', 'cardDetails("'+ data.design.results[index].SYSN +'")'))
        });
```

But in this separate instance, where the result will vary in number of fields I can't see that as being the best approach. I think I am most struggled with getting the nested `$.each()` element working at first.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ukm826br/1/

Comment: Thanks Mohit. 
Unfortunately using specific key's I.e. "DRAWING_ID" and "FILENAME" to obtain the cell value will only work for this response. Not all JSON responses returned will contain these fields. For example, this is a separate response for a different search:

`{"header": {"0": "SYSN", "1": "BRAND", "2": "MODEL", "3": "FILENAME"}, "results": {"1": {"BRAND": "AXON", "SYSN": "44/SYNC001", "MODEL": "GXG010+BPH17_GXG010", "FILENAME": "44-22-2001-Q_SYS2_SKY_1_SPORTS_5_Mixer Systems_HD"}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could save the header fields in a separate var, and build the rows according to it? E.g.:

```
function drawTable( data ) {
    $("#resultsTable").empty();
    var fieldMapping = {};
    $("#resultsTable").append(function(){
      $.each(data.header, function(index, element) {
        $("#resultsTable").append($("<th>").text(data.header[index]));
          fieldMapping[data.header[index]]=index;
      });
    }).wrapInner("<tr></tr>");

    $.each(data.results, function(index, element) {
            var tr=$('<tr/>');
            for(key in fieldMapping)
                tr.append('<td>'+element[key]+'</td>');
            $("#resultsTable").append(tr);
        });
}
```

Fiddle demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/1uz3w6ou/